# How many friendships can i analyze per request using showFriendship() in Twitter4J?

Tags: java, twitter4j

Twitter dev website says I'm limited to 15 requests per 15 minutes but I haven't seen anyone mention how much I can get per request. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The official [Twitter dev documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-show) states:

> Returns detailed information about the relationship between **two** arbitrary users.

It gives details related to requests as follows

> Requests / 15-min window (user auth)  **180**
>
> Requests / 15-min window (app auth)   **15**

The [JavaDoc of Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#showFriendship-long-long-) complies with the above definition and also mentions:

> Returns detailed information about the relationship between **two** users.

From given the aforementioned information, we can infer that you can only process *1* friendship between *2* twitter users per request.

Hope it helps.